# Xcode Not Using NSMutableArray on Table Cells

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, cocoa-touch, cell

I am building an iPhone application that is using a table cell. I set up this code to try to delete cells from the table, but it does not seem to work because I am not using a NSMutableArray. When I swipe I get the delete button but the delete button does not do anything. My question is if I am not using NSMutableArray with my table cell ho can this line: `[self.dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` work?

Code Used

```
(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES; }
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //remove the deleted object from your data source.
        //If your data source is an NSMutableArray, do this
        [self.dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link to the apple doc's on table view programming guide. [Table view programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html) It has a easy delegate method that uses `NSArray` and has an example code you can use for deleting and inserting. The code you have shown above is missing the delegate part in order to perform the delete. Take a look at listing 7.3 that maybe what your looking for.